# Consumir SOAP a partir de um rest em Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, soap, asp.net-core

Refiz a pergunta, tentando melhorá-la para melhor entendimento.

1) Criei um serviço WCF, chamado OptOutService.svc. Nesse serviço eu tenho uma interface e uma classe que implementa essa interface, conforme abaixo:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOptOutService
{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke]
   void PostOptOut(OptOutEntity cliente);
}
```

e a classe

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public class OptOutService : IOptOutService
{
    public void PostOptOut(OptOutEntity cliente)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

e minha model

```
[DataContract]
public class OptOutEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 Cpf { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Telefone { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Bandeira { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Canal { get; set; }

    public OptOutEntity(Int64 cpf, string email, string telefone, string bandeira, string canal)
    {
       Cpf = cpf;
       Email = email;
       Telefone = telefone;
       Bandeira = bandeira;
       Canal = canal;
     }
}
```

Eu preciso que no parâmetro cliente, eu pego as informações em outro serviço que foi feito em Asp.Net Core 2.0(REST) Eis o código da controller

```
[HttpPost]
public OptOutCliente Unsubscribe([FromBody]OptOutCliente cliente)
{
  if (cliente == null)
    throw new OptOutException("Informar os dados do cliente OptOut!");

  BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
  EndpointAddress wsUrl = new 
  EndpointAddress("http://localhost:64460/OptOutService.svc");

  //ServicoWSClient soapClient = new ServicoWSClient(httpBinding, wsUrl);

  return cliente;
}
```

Ou seja, preciso que esse Service consuma o SOAP e passe os valores do parâmetro **cliente**. Esse parâmetro vem de outro serviço e ele está funcionando(pelo menos no postman), pois o **Postman** simula esse outro serviço. Não sei como eu faço isso.

**Dificuldade** Rest é json e soap é xml.

Comment: Não entendi qual é a sua dúvida...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, é como eu consumo um SOAP. Como eu chamo o serviço wcf(soap)

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais fácil é adicionar a referência ao `System.Service.Model` de uma versão mais antiga do .Net (anterior ao core) e consumir o serviço via `BasicHttpBinding`

```
[HttpPost]
public OptOutCliente Unsubscribe([FromBody]OptOutCliente cliente)
{
    if (cliente == null)
        throw new OptOutException("Informar os dados do cliente OptOut!");

    BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    EndpointAddress wsUrl = new EndpointAddress("http://www.endereco.net/ServicoWS.asmx");

    ServicoWSClient soapClient = new ServicoWSClient (httpBinding, wsUrl);

    //Aqui você estará com o endpoint configurado e poderá executar os métodos que quiser      

    return cliente;
}
```

Comment: Leandro, necessito adicionar alguma referência via NuGet ou do Framework? Meu serviço é: http://localhost:64460/Service1.svc e **ServicoWsClient** o que é isso? Estou cruzão nisso

Comment: Hmmm você está consumindo um WCF, não um soap Clássico e o serviço é seu mesmo... A classe dele é `Service1` mesmo? Ps.: ServicoWS é só um nome fictício que eu usei como exemplo...

Comment: Olá Leandro, apenas corrigindo, falei com o pessoal do barramento é o serviço é um **asmx** e não **svc** conforme comentei acima. Desculpe-me pela confusão que eu fiz.